# In React, what is the correct approach to preventing a useEffect hook from executing more than once despite its dependencies having NOT changed

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have found it to be extraordinarily difficult to control the `useEffect` hook.

This experience has been incredibly debilitating and counter productive. I am losing hours upon hours having to troubleshoot the `useEffect` hook which has me second guessing using the React framework all together at this point for Angular instead. Angular components have life cycle hooks that are incredibly **clear**, practical and simple to control.

Time and time again, i am running into scenarios where an instance of my `useEffect` hook executes more than once despite **NO CHANGE** to its dependencies.

To prevent this behavior, I am finding myself constantly having to go *up the tree* to determine the cause of a component re-render which i suspect is what triggers these unwanted and subsequent executions of my `useEffect` hooks, but what do we as developers do if there is no way to avoid a component re-render and we need to prevent a `useEffect` hook from executing again as a result?

In searching SO, I have seen other developers with similar problems resorting to attempts at replicating the behavior of the former `componentDidMount` life cycle method by using the `useEffect` hook and excluding its dependencies all together as a solution like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(dependencyOne !== 'value') {
    // do some work
  }

}, []); // <-- If i am understanding the useEffect documentation this approach is not recommended.
```

It is my understanding however, that when implementing `useEffect`, if a dependency is referenced inside the hook, it **SHOULD ALWAYS** be included as a dependency in the closing array like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(dependencyOne === 'value') {
    // do some work
  }

}, [dependencyOne]);
```

And that does make sense. `useEffect` will, *by design*, run again whenever a dependency changes, as intended.

However, **TO BE CLEAR**, i am running into issues where my `useEffect` hooks are executing more than once despite the fact that their dependencies have **NOT CHANGED**.

*Thus, the question, if we cannot prevent a component that contains a `useEffect` hook from a re-render, what is the best practice approach to prevent that `useEffect` hook from executing more than once when it is known that the `useEffect` has dependencies that have NOT changed?*

I have been doing the following which to me just does not feel right nor practical in situations which are much more complex that reference multiple props or local states:

First, *outside* of my component, i define a boolean:

```
...
let initalChecksComplete = false; // <-- boolean used to control useEffect execution
const MyComponent: React.FC<ContainerProps> = (props) => {
...
```

And then inside my useEffect hook i do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!initalChecksComplete && dependencyThatDoesNotChange === 'value') {
    initalChecksComplete = true;
    // do some work
  }
  console.log('Confirmation that this hook executes more than once.');
}, [dependencyThatDoesNotChange]);
```

Seems to me that it should not be necessary to use booleans in this way to prevent subsequent execution despite knowing factually that none of the dependencies have changed, and i suspect it goes against best practices in a React application.

Looking at the React documentation, it seems that React *sort of* suggests that it is ok to [exclude dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), but this explanation is confusing. They *seem* to suggest that if we find ourselves having to exclude dependencies that we should look to write a different implementation entirely to achieve what is needed and avoid the practice of excluding dependencies all together. That correct?

[image: note taken from React site]

**NOTE:** It may also be the case that i am running into multiple `useEffect` execution issues due to the following issue, *still open at the time of this writing*, on github surrounding `Restrict Mode` which may be causing my hooks to execute unexpectedly: [github issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/pull/4650/files) can anyone confirm if this could be true?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#gradually-adopting-concurrent-features), strict mode in react 18 got stricter, and therefore will mount and unmount your component **in dev mode only**. React will not re-run useEffect unless dependencies **have** changed. To debug this, here's what I suggest:

1. Disable strict mode and try to reproduce the issue, see if it's just strict mode
2. If that doesn't do it, verify that your dependencies haven't changed due to a parent re-render
3. Finally, check the type of your dependencies, people have run into situations with with object types, that when a new object is created, useEffect would re-run

That's how I'd go about it.

Comment: Restrict Mode may in-fact be the cause of problems i have been dealing with. Thank you and i will test this theory and come back with my results.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a dependency to useEffect's array, it won't run until that dependency changes. So maybe the dependency is state variable that got updated or your dependency is a reference type which means that it will be recreated again (in this case wrap it with useCallback hook) or maybe a parent component re-renders which causes this component to re-render again.

Comment: In my situation, my useEffect hooks are executing more than once despite having dependencies which have NOT changed.

Comment: if you can share your code it will be helpful to everybody to understand your situation. If you can't make sure you're dependecies are not reference type or maybe it is a child component that is re-rendered when the parent re-renders

Comment: I wanted to include specific code, but it would require including so many parts of my application for it to be clear that my dependencies have not changed. To avoid having to do that i tried to use a generic and simple example instead. It is likely a parent component re-render that is the cause, and thus the question, if we cannot prevent the re-render, how do we prevent useEffect from executing more than once when it should not.